# leaflet.draw: check there is an existing layer

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have this mousemove function:

```
$("#mapContainer").on("mousemove", "#colorpicker"+mapNo, function(event){
        //do something here
        //layer.setStyle({color: color, fillColor: color}); 

    });
```

Whenever I delete the comment for *layer.setStyle* in the mousemove function, I get an error **"layer is not defined"** so I want the mousemove function to get called when a layer is already existing in the map. I have this function where the layer is defined:

```
function drawCreated(e) {
        type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

        layer.addTo(drawnItems); 
        console.log(type, ' drawn', layer);

        //for drawing
        if (type === 'circle') {
            var theCenterPt = layer.getLatLng();

            var theRadius = layer.getRadius();
            var center = [theCenterPt.lng,theCenterPt.lat]; 
            console.log(center);
            points['lng'] = theCenterPt.lng;
            points['lat'] = theCenterPt.lat;
            points['radius'] = theRadius;

            console.log(points);

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
            //drawnItems.setStyle({color: color, fillColor: color});

        } 

        if(map.hasLayer(layer)){
            console.log("true");
            //must call the mousemove function here or mousemove will work when there is a layer
        }else{
            console.log("false");
        }


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this isn't an XY problem - can you describe what behaviour you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to change the color of the layer using the mousemove function. but i always get an error saying layer is not defined because there is no layer in the map, that's why i want to check, if there is a layer, the mousemove will work but if there is not, it will not work.

Comment: I do not understand what your goal is. Do you want the color of a layer to change when the layer is moved or when the mouse moves in general? Should all layers change the color or only certain layers?

Comment: @FalkeDesign I want to change the color of the layer when i move cursor in the colorpicker. it should change a certain layer which is the layer that i draw.

Answer (score 0):

Look into my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/95g08z71/10/

you have to replace "circle" with your layer.

```
// https://iro.js.org/guide.html#color-picker-events
colorPicker.on(["color:init", "color:change"], function(color){
      circle.setStyle({fillColor: color.hexString});
});
```

To say what not working in your code, I need a working example. Maybe you can create a fiddle or upload your code to a website.